# Finding the Lie Algebra su(2) via the Implicit function Theorem

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, implicit-function-theorem, unitary-matrices

I don't think this question has been asked before, however if it has, feel free to redirect me.
I want to find the Lie Algebra su(2) of the Lie Group SU(2) via the Implicit function Theorem (i know how to do it using exp). This is how i do it (question at the end):

$$
SU(2) = \{ A \in Mat(2,C) | A^*A = I, \; \det(A) = 1 \}
$$

Define the Function
$$
\psi: \{ A \in Mat(2,C) | \det(A) = 1 \} \rightarrow \{ A \in Mat(2,C) | A^* = A \}
$$
$$
A \mapsto A^*A - I
$$

It is true that

1. $\psi(I) = 0$
2. $\psi^{-1}(\{0\}) = SU(2)$

Consider the derivative
$$
D\psi(A)[B] = \frac{d}{dt} \psi(A + tB) \Bigg|_{t=0} = A B^* + BA^*
$$
It follows that
$$
D\psi(I) = B + B^*
$$
The derivative is surjective at $I$ because for an arbitrary $C = C^*$
$$
D\psi(I)[\frac{1}{2}C] = \frac{1}{2}C + \frac{1}{2}C^* = C
$$
The Implicit Function Theorem now states that $SU(2)$ is a smooth manifold whose tangent space at $I$ is given by
$$
T_I SU(2) = \ker(D\psi(I)) = su(2) = \{B \in Mat(2,C) | B + B^* = 0, \; \det(B) = 1 \}
$$
However, this is not what $su(2)$ should be. $su(2)$ should be given by
$$
 su(2) = \{B \in Mat(2,C) | B + B^* = 0, \; \textbf{trace}(B) = 0 \}
$$
I tried to use the two properties $B + B^* = 0, \; \det(B) = 1$ to derive $\text{trace}(B) = 0$ but i did not succed. Now i have the feeling my mistake is rooted deeper.
My question is: what is my mistake and how to do it right.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know what is the lie algebra of $SL(2, \mathbb C)$?

Comment: Yes, i do. But i dont understand how that is related to my question

Comment: Can you write the definition down in your post? It seems you've got it wrong.

Comment: like that? SL(2,C) = {A∈Mat(2,C)|det(A)=1} i replaced it in the question as well

Comment: I am not talking about $SL(2, \mathbb C)$, but the Lie algebra of it.....

Comment: But i did not even mention it in the question? sl(2,C) = {A∈Mat(2,C)|tr(A)=0}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you differentiate $\psi : SL(2, \mathbb C) \to H$ (where $H$ is the space of all Hermetian matrices), you have

$$ D\psi (I) : T_I SL(2, \mathbb C) \to T_0H$$
and from what you prove, $T_ISU(2)$ is the kernel of this map. So

\begin{align}
 T_ISU (2) &= \ker  (D\psi (I) : T_I SL(2, \mathbb C) \to T_0H) \\
&= \{ B \in T_I SL(2, \mathbb C) :  D\psi (I) (B) = 0 \} \\
&= \{ B \in T_I SL(2, \mathbb C) :  B +B^* = 0 \} \\
\end{align}

Since
$$T_I SL(2, \mathbb C) = \{ B \in Mat(2, \mathbb C) : \operatorname{trace} B = 0\},$$
one has

$$T_ISU (2) =  \{ B \in Mat(2, \mathbb C) : \operatorname{trace} B = 0, B+B^* = 0\}.$$

I guess, at the end of the day, I don't see why you have $\det B = 1$ there.

Comment: But why is the kernel $\text{ker}(D\psi(I))$ given by the traceless matrices? If
$$
D\psi(I)[B] = B^* + B
$$
i can find matrices with non zero trace that fulfill $D\psi(I)[B] = 0$

Comment: Do you understand that the domain of $D\psi (I)$ is $T_ISL(2, \mathbb C)$? @vreithinger

Comment: I do not, thank you though now i know where my problem was ill read more on that